# find the size of array through a function if we aren't passing size variable in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am learning c++ and facing some some difficulties in writing some code like how can we count the number of elements of an array through a function suppose we are not passing the variable for size ![enter image description here][1]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void check(int arr[], int s);

int main () 
{
   int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
   check(array,5);
}
void check(int arr[], int s) 
{        

   for (int i = arr[0]; i <= arr[s]; i++)
    {
     s=arr[s];
        }
        cout<<"size is : "<<s<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you've already tried, Stack Overflow isn't here to write code for you.

Comment: Don't post images of code - post the code itself as text.

Comment: You not using a proper container like `std::vector` is a deliberate handicap set by your teacher? My first instinct would be to write my own container class, if allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You use a template, and take a deduced array by reference instead of a pointer

```
template <size_t N>
void check(int (&)[N])
{
    std::cout << "Size is : " << N << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

Comment: Be careful. This is true inside of main(), but once passed to the function it's has decayed to a pointer and `size` would be 1 and not 5.